# Is their a way to find the maximum video resolution that a particular phone can play

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, video, screen-resolution

## Maximum video resolution ##

- How can we find the maximum video resolution a phone can handle.
- Is their any code that can run and find out the maximum resolution.

---

In YouTube application i could find that the quality of the video is set after checking the phones specification. will some thing like that can figure out an answer

Comment: refer the following question on SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761787/maximum-playable-video-resolution-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Only screen resolution of device, after that is only benchmarking. For example count FPS of high res video during playback.